# Target class App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I get this error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController] does not exist.

I guess the problem is in the route
My web.php:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController;
Route::get('change/password', [App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordView'])->middleware('auth')->name('change/password');
Route::post('change/password/db', [App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordDB'])->name('change/password/db');
```

Comment: assuming you have the namespace correct on your controller, have you tried clearing the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you forgot to put `\` when calling your controllers.

Change that :

```
Route::get('change/password', [App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordView'])->middleware('auth')->name('change/password');
Route::post('change/password/db', [App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordDB'])->name('change/password/db');
```

by that :

```
Route::get('change/password', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordView'])->middleware('auth')->name('change/password');
Route::post('change/password/db', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordDB'])->name('change/password/db');
```

Comment: i have tried that didn't work

Comment: I fixed that it was just a misspell in the controller's name, Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Add the controller at the top of your `web.php` route file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController;
```

Then define the routes as

```
Route::get('change/password', [UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordView'])->middleware('auth')->name('change/password');
Route::post('change/password/db', [UserManagementController::class, 'changePasswordDB'])->name('change/password/db');
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `composer dump-autoload` does the trick, in case you've recently added that controller.

Also verify the `namespace` declaration in `UserManagementController.php` once.

Comment: i get this when i run composer dump-autoload : Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController located in C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel8ecommerce/app\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.Class App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController located in C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel8ecommerce/app\Http\Controllers\UserManagamentController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

Comment: @Mithrandir Please refer to the second part of my answer - or the answer linked above. Apparently you are missing the `namespace` declaration altogether and that's why it will not work.